# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'slider_img' of non-object

Tags: laravel

[i got this error when i want to show a single project details in view ErrorException (E_ERROR) Trying to get property 'slider_img' of non-object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lz6B.png)

> Route

```
 Route::get('project/{id}', 'HomeController@project')->name('project');
```

> View single project

```
    @extends('welcome')
@section('content')

         @foreach($projects as $project)
                        <div class="img-thumbnail border-0 border-radius-0 p-0 d-block">
                            <img src="{{ \Voyager::image( $project->slider_img  ) }}" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

@endsection

> Here is my controller function

Comment: add your controller function. it seems your `project` variable is not an object.

Comment: public function project($id)
    {
        $projects = Project::find($id);
        if (empty($projects)){
            session()->flash('Error','Project Not Found');
            return redirect('/');
        }
        return view('frontend.projects.singleproject',compact('projects'));
    }

thats my controller function

Answer (score 0):

Change Your your controller function something like this -:

public function project($id) {
 $project = Project::find($id); //insted of projects use project as you will get only single project with this
 if (empty($project)){
  session()->flash('Error','Project Not Found');
  return redirect('/'); } return view('frontend.projects.singleproject',compact('project')); 
  }

Then in the view file do something like this

@extends('welcome')
@section('content')

{{$project->slider_img}}

There is no need to use for each for single project

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a single object. So you don't need to iterate it. Remove the `foreach` loop. just write your code like below

```
<div class="img-thumbnail border-0 border-radius-0 p-0 d-block">
    <img src="{{ \Voyager::image( $projects->slider_img  ) }}" class="img-fluid border-radius-0" alt="">
</div>
```